# Create sets of files with some set of records

Tags: php

I am trying to create set of file. Have 100 records every file will have 10 records if it exceed 10 record it will create new file.and store next data in new file

Created file but all the data is coming in 1 file.

```
<?php
function wh_BATCH($Batch_msg,$count)
{
    $log_filename = "BATCH";
    if (!file_exists($log_filename)) 
    {
        // create directory/folder uploads.
        mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
    }

if($count == 5)
    {
        $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_1.txt';
        file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);       
    }
    else
    {
        $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_' . date('d-M-Y') . '.txt';
        file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);        
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    wh_BATCH("hello world ".$i,5);    
}

?>
```

**Output**

10 files will be created BATCH_1.txt,********,BATCH_10.txt in which BATCH_1 will have

`BATCH_1.txt Hello world 1 to Hello world 10`

`BATCH_2.txt Hello world 11 to Hello world 20`

`BATCH_3.txt Hello world 21 to Hello world 30`

*
*
*

`BATCH_10.txt Hello world 91 to Hello world 100`

Please suggest

[image: File Output]

[image: File Data]

**Edited**

```
<?php 
 for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
 { 
  wh_BATCH("hello world ".$i, $i);    
  } 

  function wh_BATCH($Batch_msg,$count)
  {
  $log_filename = "BATCH";
  if (!file_exists($log_filename)) 
  {
      // create directory/folder uploads.
    mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
   }

  $number = (float)$count/10;
  $number++;

    $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_'.$number.'.txt';
    file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
}
?>
```

[image: OutPut]

Above file should have only 10 Files Each file should have 10 records 
BATCH_1.txt --- BATCH_10.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    wh_BATCH("hello world ".$i,5);    
}
```

In this FOR you are always passing 5 as second parameter.

```
if($count == 5)
{
    $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_1.txt';
    file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);       
}
```

That's why this part of the wh_BATCH() function is always executed. This part always append to BATCH_1.txt

In order to achieve your goal, you should do this

First, pass to the wh_BATCH() function the value of i

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    wh_BATCH("hello world ".$i, $i);    
}
```

Then, inside the function, you could do something like this

```
$number = intVal($count/10);
$number++;
$log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_'.$number.'.txt';
file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

This would be the function

```
function wh_BATCH($Batch_msg,$count)
{
    $log_filename = "BATCH";
    if (!file_exists($log_filename)) 
    {
        // create directory/folder uploads.
        mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
    }

    $number = intVal($count/10);
    $number++;
    $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_'.$number.'.txt';
    file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

TESTED WORKING CODE ON PHP 5.6

```
<?php
   function wh_BATCH($Batch_msg,$count)
   {
      $log_filename = "BATCH";
      if (!file_exists($log_filename)) 
      {
        // create directory/folder uploads.
        mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
      }

      $number = intVal($count/10);
      $number++;

      $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/BATCH_'.$number.'.txt';
      file_put_contents($log_file_data, $Batch_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
   }

   for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
   { 
     wh_BATCH("hello world ".$i, $i);    
   }
```

Comment: can you please suggest how can i solve this with some snippets

Comment: Only 1 record is getting inserted in 1 file can you please see the Output file which i have attached. There should be 10 record in 1 file with File name as ``BATCH_2.txt(Hello world 1 to Hello world 10)`` next file will have BATCH_2.txt(Hello world 11 to Hello world 20) please suggest

Comment: yes in my BATCH folder BATCH_1.1.txt is getting created which has 1 record it should have 10 recods . no of files created is 100 text files there should be only 10 text file each file should have 10 records [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZnwl.png)

Comment: Edit (float) casting with (int) casting and try now

Comment: What's the problem this time?

Comment: It is giving the same output 100 files are getting generated where each file has 1 records it should have 10 records. For each record it is creating a file after 10 record it should create new file with new Name as BATCH_n ``(where n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)``

Comment: I fixed it, use intVal() instead of (int)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It is creating only one file BATCH_2.txt which has all the 100 records

Comment: @daoootim I edited the answer with the working code I tested. It does exactly what you want to achieve. Which version of PHP are you running? It works on PHP 5.6